# .DS_Store in .gitignore: unnecessary?

Tags: git, gitignore

I've read about people adding .DS_Store to their .gitignore files, but I did a quick test using Git 1.7.6 and I'm not sure it's even necessary. What do you think?

```
johndoe@John-Does-MacBook-Pro:~$ mkdir test
johndoe@John-Does-MacBook-Pro:~$ cd test/
johndoe@John-Does-MacBook-Pro:~/test$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/johndoe/test/.git/
johndoe@John-Does-MacBook-Pro:~/test$ touch foo.txt
johndoe@John-Does-MacBook-Pro:~/test$ touch .DS_Store
johndoe@John-Does-MacBook-Pro:~/test$ touch bar.txt
johndoe@John-Does-MacBook-Pro:~/test$ touch .DS_Store2
johndoe@John-Does-MacBook-Pro:~/test$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .DS_Store2
#   bar.txt
#   foo.txt
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
johndoe@John-Does-MacBook-Pro:~/test$ git config -l
user.name=John Doe
user.email=johndoe@example.com
color.ui=true
core.editor=mate -w
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
```

Comment: What is .DS_Store2 in reference to? If it's a project type you might consider adding an additional tag for it.

Comment: Just add .DS_Store to your global gitignore file, that way you don't need to mess with individual repositories.  Same goes for *~, #*#, if you use Emacs or Vi.

Comment: @Michael I was just illustrating that I didn't have something funky going on that was hiding hidden files from Git. I suppose I could've used ".hidden" instead of ".DS_Store2".

Comment: @DietrichEpp The thing is, I'd like *any* Mac user to be able to work with this repository and not have to see .DS_Store files in the output of `git status`. If that requires adding .DS_Store to the repository's ".gitignore" file then that's fine but if it's not necessary that I won't bother with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a recursive grep through the entire source code of git, and didn't see any reference to ".DS_Store" except in the .gitignore of the git-gui directory.

This means that git isn't going to automatically ignore that file (unless it's patched in special in the MacOS build of git or something odd like that).

Possibly the reason it's ignoring it for you may be that you have it in your global ignores.

Comment: Thanks for doing that! I'm 99% sure I never personally added it to my global ignores. I'm guessing `git config -l` would've shown it if that were the case. I installed Git using [this](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer). Any other thoughts?

Comment: I looked into it more and found out [here](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/wiki/BuildYourOwn) that the following snippet of code is executed: `sudo sh -c "echo .DS_Store >> /usr/local/git/share/git-core/templates/info/exclude"`. So it appears that whenever `git init` is run, that file is copied to the new repository's ".git/info/exclude" file. I suppose that's OK because according to [this page](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files), "this method can be used for locally-generated files that you don't expect other users to generate" (like non-Mac Users). Thanks again!